# Parsing Chars In SQL Using PATINDEX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to validate a string using raw sql;
tried using:

```
DECLARE @AlphaNumeric varchar(50)
SET @AlphaNumeric = '1017a'


SELECT  SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumeric, 1, (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric) - 1)) AS 'Numeric',
SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumeric, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric), DATALENGTH(@AlphaNumeric)) AS 'Alpha'
```

But if the user types 101a7a,this doesnt work properly;what i want to do exactly is;
I want the variable always to be, numeric+alphanumeric,lenght doesnt matter.
For example :

```
2303A OK
23A434A NOT OK
A344 NOT OK.
```

4324AAC OK

This would be dead easy if i could do it in Regex but sql gives me headaches :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letters followed by numbers are OK; Numbers followed by letters aren't; All characters must be letters or numbers. Hence...

```
select * from yourtable
where yourfield like '%[0-9][a-z]%'
and not (yourfield like '%[a-z][0-9]%')
and not (yourfield like '%[^0-9a-z]%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.  At least, it works on your sample data:

```
with t as (
    select '2303A' as col union all
    select '23A434A' union all
    select 'A344'
)
select *,
       (case when col like '%[0-9]%' and
                  substring(col, patindex('%[A-Z]%', col), len(col)) not like '%[^A-Z]%'
             then 'OK'
             else 'NOT OK'
        end)
from t;
```

The two conditions are.  First check that the character string has a number somewhere.  Then, check that there are only letters after the first letter is found.  I'm assuming that all letters are uppercase.

EDIT:

There might be an easier way.  You can check that a number is followed by a letter somewhere in the string, but that a letter is never followed by a number.  For this, you only need like:

```
select (case when col not like '%[^A-Z0-9]%' and
                  col like '%[0-9][A-Z]%' and
                  col not like '%[A-Z][0-9]%'
             then 'OK'
             else 'NOT OK'
         end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach that should work in your situation. Basically identify the position of the last integer and compare it to the position of the first non integer. You can get the position of the last integer like this

```
len(@AlphaNumeric) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Reverse(@AlphaNumeric))+1
```

and you can get the position of the first non integer like this

```
 PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric)
```

so that would make your where clause (where all integers precede any non integers like this

```
Where (len(@AlphaNumeric) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Reverse(@AlphaNumeric))+1 ) < PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric)
```